# Are there any way to apply regexp in java ignoring letter case?

Tags: java, regex, string

Simple example: we have string "Some sample string Of Text". And I want to filter out all stop words (i.e. "some" and "of") but I don't want to change letter case of other words which should be retained.

If letter case was unimportant I would do this:

```
str.toLowerCase().replaceAll ("a|the|of|some|any", "");
```

Is there an "ignore case" solution with regular expressions in java?

Comment: The provided answers all compile the regexes. You really should do this if you apply you patterns many times (inside a loop?). It will give you a HUGE performance/speed gain.

Comment: exhuma: thanks for the suggestion, but it was just an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the inline case-insensitive modifier:

```
str.replaceAll ("(?i)a|the|of|some|any", "");
```

Comment: I'll try. If I understand correctly, "inline case-insensitive modifier" is `(?i)`, am I right?

Comment: @Roman: Exactly. There are others, too: http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html (Scroll down to "Using The Pattern Class").

Comment: you can also do partial case insensitivity IIRC `"(?i:a)bc"` is equivalent (in my Locale) to "[aA]bc"

Comment: @kts: thanks, I think only a few people know about this possibility.

Comment: @Tomalak: Why not just link directly to the Pattern javadoc? :) http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: @Esko: Because I knew *you* would do it, so I waited. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do the trick as well:

```
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("a|the|of|some|any", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(str);
        String result = matcher.replaceAll("");
```